# How to reformat and re-install an old G5

Tags: g5, install

I was given an old G5, and the existing installed OS is locked, and I don't have the password. I don't care about erasing its whole content. I have a bunch of CDs, and I want to know how can I restart this machine so it boots from the CD and reformat the whole system. I am very new to MAC world.

I realise this is a MAC 101 question type, but I need to start somewhere......

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restart while holding down the <kbd>C</kbd> key to boot from a valid Mac OS X Install CD / DVD for that G5 based Mac. To pick and choose what disk your machine can boot from hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key while starting the Mac.

Also depending on which version of Mac OS X is installed there are different ways to reset the password in single user mode. This may be an option for you if you just want to  unlock and add / remove users and you have a startup CD/DVD for that Mac.

See  [Changing or resetting an account password](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1274) for some instructions on how to reset the password.

Answer (score -1):

Do we have a FAQ? This should be on it.
Have a look at : http://www.theinstructional.com/guides/how-to-re-run-the-os-x-setup-assistant

That'll give you working login for the system and you can start your repairs from there.